# Error when I try to execute the command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento2

I have a installation of magento 2.2 in linux mint, I'm using lampp.

I am wanting to change the installation language and when I try to execute the command: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_AR I have the following error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wWW1.png)

It also happens to me with other commands like the following:

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

Someone has an idea that it may be happening or that the problem is due.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1: remove pub static content 
  Command:rm -R pub/static/*

2: remove var Cache 
 Command:rm -R var/*

then give permission 777 to both folders

then run deploy command